# Ado.Net and Async insert of many rows to db

Tags: c#, async-await, ado.net

I have implemented repository in Ado.Net which insert data to many tables. I insert all in one transaction and use async/await to improve performances.
If you have any suggestions have to improve my code I would be grateful.

```
using MonitoringTool.Common.DomainModelsNew;
using MonitoringTool.Common.Extensions;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Telexis.Util;

namespace DatabaseAccessNew.Repositories
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Import with Ado.Net
    /// </summary>
    internal class ImportRepository
    {
        private readonly ILogWrapper _logWrapper;
        private static readonly string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MonitoringTool"].ConnectionString;

        public ImportRepository(ILogWrapper logWrapper)
        {
            _logWrapper = logWrapper;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Import statuses from monitoring information to database with ADO.NET
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="monitoringInformation"></param>
        /// <returns>True if insert is successful else false</returns>
        public async Task<bool> ImportStatuses(MonitoringInformation monitoringInformation)
        {
            bool success = false;
            SqlTransaction trans = null;
            try
            {
                using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    await connection.OpenAsync();
                    using (trans = connection.BeginTransaction())
                    {
                        success = await ImportStatuses(monitoringInformation, trans);
                        trans.Commit();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logWrapper.Error(ex.Message);
                if (ex.InnerException != null)
                {
                    _logWrapper.Error(ex.InnerException.Message);
                }
                _logWrapper.Debug(ex.ToString());

                // Handle the exception if the transaction fails to commit.
                try
                {
                    // Attempt to roll back the transaction.
                    trans.Rollback();
                }
                catch (Exception exRollback)
                {
                    _logWrapper.Error(exRollback.Message);
                    _logWrapper.Debug(exRollback.ToString());
                }
            }

            return success;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Import all statuses to db
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="monitoringInformation"></param>
        /// <param name="trans">Transaction</param>
        /// <returns>True if insert is successful else false</returns>
        private async Task<bool> ImportStatuses(MonitoringInformation monitoringInformation, SqlTransaction trans)
        {
            int monitoringInformationId = await ImportMonitoringInformation(monitoringInformation, trans);

            var importEquipmentStatusTask = ImportEquipmentStatus(monitoringInformation.Equipment, monitoringInformationId, trans);
            var importDeviceStausesTask = ImportDeviceStatuses(monitoringInformation.Devices, monitoringInformationId, trans);
            var importInterfaceStausTask = ImportInterfaceStatuses(monitoringInformation.Interfaces, monitoringInformationId, trans);
            var importHardwareComponentStatusTask = ImportHardwareComponentStatuses(monitoringInformation.HardwareComponents, monitoringInformation.EODs, monitoringInformationId, trans);

            await Task.WhenAll(importEquipmentStatusTask, importDeviceStausesTask, importInterfaceStausTask, importHardwareComponentStatusTask);
            return true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Import basic information about Monitoring
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="monitoringInformation">Monitoring information</param>
        /// <param name="trans">Transaction</param>
        /// <returns>Monitoring information identifier</returns>
        private async Task<int> ImportMonitoringInformation(MonitoringInformation monitoringInformation, SqlTransaction trans)
        {
            if (monitoringInformation == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(monitoringInformation));
            }

            const string query = @" INSERT INTO dbo.MonitoringInformation ([Filename] ,FileType ,GeneratedDate ,Version ,InsertedDateTime)
                                    VALUES (@Filename,@FileType,@GeneratedDate,@Version,@InsertedDateTime);
                                    SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)";
            try
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, trans.Connection, trans))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Filename", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FileType", SqlDbType.Int);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@GeneratedDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Version", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@InsertedDateTime", SqlDbType.DateTime);

                    cmd.Parameters["@Filename"].Value = monitoringInformation.Filename;
                    cmd.Parameters["@FileType"].Value = monitoringInformation.FileType;
                    cmd.Parameters["@GeneratedDate"].Value = monitoringInformation.GeneratedDate;
                    cmd.Parameters["@Version"].Value = monitoringInformation.Version;
                    cmd.Parameters["@InsertedDateTime"].Value = monitoringInformation.InsertedDateTime;
                    return (int)await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                _logWrapper.Error($"Error in {nameof(ImportMonitoringInformation)}");
                throw;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Import equipment status
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="equipment">Equipment</param>
        /// <param name="monitoringInformationId">Monitoring information identifier</param>
        /// <param name="trans">Transaction</param>
        private async Task ImportEquipmentStatus(Equipment equipment, int monitoringInformationId, SqlTransaction trans)
        {
            if (equipment == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            const string query = @" INSERT INTO  dbo.EquipmentStatus (EquipmentId,MonitoringInformationId,Status,LastUpdate,GpsTime,Position,Trip,GpsData)
                                    SELECT e.EquipmentId,@MonitoringInformationId,@Status,@LastUpdate,@GpsTime,@Position,@Trip,@GpsData
                                    FROM dbo.Equipment e
                                    WHERE e.Name = @EquipmentName;";

            try
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, trans.Connection, trans))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MonitoringInformationId", SqlDbType.Int);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastUpdate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@GpsTime", SqlDbType.DateTime);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Position", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Trip", SqlDbType.Int);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@GpsData", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@EquipmentName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);

                    cmd.Parameters["@MonitoringInformationId"].Value = monitoringInformationId;
                    cmd.Parameters["@Status"].Value = equipment.EquipmentStatus.Status;
                    cmd.Parameters["@LastUpdate"].Value = equipment.EquipmentStatus.LastUpdate;
                    cmd.Parameters["@GpsTime"].Value = equipment.EquipmentStatus.GpsTime.DbValueOrNull();
                    cmd.Parameters["@Position"].Value = equipment.EquipmentStatus.Position;
                    cmd.Parameters["@Trip"].Value = equipment.EquipmentStatus.Trip.DbValueOrNull();
                    cmd.Parameters["@GpsData"].Value = equipment.EquipmentStatus.GpsData;
                    cmd.Parameters["@EquipmentName"].Value = equipment.Name;
                    await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                _logWrapper.Error($"Error in {nameof(ImportEquipmentStatus)}");
                throw;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Import device statuses
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="devices">Devices</param>
        /// <param name="monitoringInformationId">Monitoring information identifier</param>
        /// <param name="trans">Transaction</param>
        private async Task ImportDeviceStatuses(IEnumerable<Device> devices, int monitoringInformationId, SqlTransaction trans)
        {
            if (devices?.Any() != true)
            {
                return;
            }
            const string query = @" INSERT INTO  dbo.DeviceStatus (DeviceId,MonitoringInformationId,Status,[File])
                                    SELECT d.DeviceId, @MonitoringInformationId , @Status, @File
                                    FROM dbo.Device d
                                    WHERE d.Name = @DeviceName; ";

            try
            {
                var importTasks = new List<Task<int>>();
                foreach (var device in devices)
                {
                    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, trans.Connection, trans))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DeviceName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@MonitoringInformationId", SqlDbType.Int);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.NChar);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@File", SqlDbType.NChar);

                        cmd.Parameters["@DeviceName"].Value = device.Name;
                        cmd.Parameters["@MonitoringInformationId"].Value = monitoringInformationId;
                        cmd.Parameters["@Status"].Value = device.DeviceStatus.Status;
                        cmd.Parameters["@File"].Value = device.DeviceStatus.File;
                        importTasks.Add(cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync());
                    }
                }
                await Task.WhenAll(importTasks);
            }
            catch
            {
                _logWrapper.Error($"Error in {nameof(ImportDeviceStatuses)}");
                throw;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Import eod statuses
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="eods">Eods</param>
        /// <param name="monitoringInformationId">Monitoring information identifier</param>
        /// <param name="hardwareComponentId">Hardware component identifier</param>
        /// <param name="trans">Transaction</param>
        private async Task ImportEodStatuses(IEnumerable<Eod> eods, int monitoringInformationId, int hardwareComponentId, SqlTransaction trans)
        {
            const string query = @" INSERT INTO  dbo.EODStatus (EodId,MonitoringInformationId,HardwareComponent_HardwareComponentId,FileType,FileVersion,Location,EffectiveDate,Versiontype)
                                    SELECT e.EODId,@MonitoringInformationId,@HardwareComponent_HardwareComponentId,@FileType,@FileVersion,@Location,@EffectiveDate,@Versiontype
                                    FROM dbo.EOD e
                                    WHERE e.FileVersion = @Name; ";

            try
            {
                var importTasks = new List<Task<int>>();
                foreach (var eod in eods)
                {
                    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, trans.Connection, trans))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@MonitoringInformationId", SqlDbType.Int);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@HardwareComponent_HardwareComponentId", SqlDbType.Int);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FileType", SqlDbType.Int);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FileVersion", SqlDbType.SmallInt);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Location", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@EffectiveDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Versiontype", SqlDbType.SmallInt);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar);

                        cmd.Parameters["@MonitoringInformationId"].Value = monitoringInformationId;
                        cmd.Parameters["@HardwareComponent_HardwareComponentId"].Value = hardwareComponentId;
                        cmd.Parameters["@FileType"].Value = eod.EodStatus.FileType;
                        cmd.Parameters["@FileVersion"].Value = eod.EodStatus.FileVersion;
                        cmd.Parameters["@Location"].Value = eod.EodStatus.Location;
                        cmd.Parameters["@EffectiveDate"].Value = eod.EodStatus.EffectiveDate;
                        cmd.Parameters["@Versiontype"].Value = eod.EodStatus.VersionType;
                        cmd.Parameters["@Name"].Value = eod.FileVersion;
                        importTasks.Add(cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync());
                    }
                }
                await Task.WhenAll(importTasks);
            }
            catch
            {
                _logWrapper.Error($"Error in {nameof(ImportEodStatuses)}");
                throw;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Import interface statuses
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="interfaces">Interfaces</param>
        /// <param name="monitoringInformationId">Monitoring information identifier</param>
        /// <param name="trans">Transaction</param>
        private async Task ImportInterfaceStatuses(IEnumerable<Interface> interfaces, int monitoringInformationId, SqlTransaction trans)
        {
            if (interfaces?.Any() != true)
            {
                return;
            }
            const string query = @" INSERT INTO  dbo.InterfaceStatus (InterfaceId,MonitoringInformationId,Status,StatusTime,LastUpdate)
                                    SELECT i.InterfaceId, @MonitoringInformationId , @Status, @StatusTime, @LastUpdate
                                    FROM dbo.Interface i
                                    WHERE i.Name = @InterfaceName; ";

            try
            {
                var importTasks = new List<Task<int>>();
                foreach (var interf in interfaces)
                {
                    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, trans.Connection, trans))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@MonitoringInformationId", SqlDbType.Int);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.NChar);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@StatusTime", SqlDbType.DateTime);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastUpdate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@InterfaceName", SqlDbType.NChar);

                        cmd.Parameters["@MonitoringInformationId"].Value = monitoringInformationId;
                        cmd.Parameters["@Status"].Value = interf.InterfaceStatus.Status;
                        cmd.Parameters["@StatusTime"].Value = interf.InterfaceStatus.StatusTime;
                        cmd.Parameters["@LastUpdate"].Value = interf.InterfaceStatus.LastUpdate;
                        cmd.Parameters["@InterfaceName"].Value = interf.Name;
                        importTasks.Add(cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync());
                    }
                }
                await Task.WhenAll(importTasks);
            }
            catch
            {
                _logWrapper.Error($"Error in {nameof(ImportInterfaceStatuses)}");
                throw;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Import hardware component statuses
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hardwareComponents">hardware components</param>
        /// <param name="eods">Eods</param>
        /// <param name="monitoringInformationId">Monitoring information identifier</param>
        /// <param name="trans">Transaction</param>
        private async Task ImportHardwareComponentStatuses(IEnumerable<HardwareComponent> hardwareComponents, IEnumerable<Eod> eods, int monitoringInformationId, SqlTransaction trans)
        {
            if (hardwareComponents?.Any() != true)
            {
                return;
            }
            const string query = @" INSERT INTO  dbo.HardwareStatusInformation(MonitoringInformationId,HardwareComponentId,UpTime,RamTotal,RamFree,RamUnit,DiskTotal,DiskFree,LastUpdate,GroupId)
                                    SELECT @MonitoringInformationId,h.HardwareComponentId,@UpTime,@RamTotal,@RamFree,@RamUnit,@DiskTotal,@DiskFree,@LastUpdate,@GroupId
                                    FROM dbo.HardwareComponent h
                                    WHERE h.DeviceID = @Name; 
                                    SELECT HardwareComponentId FROM dbo.HardwareComponent WHERE DeviceID = @Name";

            try
            {
                var importSoftwareComponentStatusesTasks = new List<Task>();
                var importEodStatusesTasks = new List<Task>();
                foreach (var hardwarecomponent in hardwareComponents)
                {
                    int hardwareComponentId;
                    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, trans.Connection, trans))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@MonitoringInformationId", SqlDbType.Int);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UpTime", SqlDbType.BigInt);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@RamTotal", SqlDbType.BigInt);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@RamFree", SqlDbType.BigInt);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@RamUnit", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DiskTotal", SqlDbType.BigInt);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DiskFree", SqlDbType.BigInt);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastUpdate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@GroupId", SqlDbType.Int);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar);

                        cmd.Parameters["@MonitoringInformationId"].Value = monitoringInformationId;
                        cmd.Parameters["@UpTime"].Value = hardwarecomponent.HardwareStatusInformation.UpTime;
                        cmd.Parameters["@RamTotal"].Value = hardwarecomponent.HardwareStatusInformation.RamTotal;
                        cmd.Parameters["@RamFree"].Value = hardwarecomponent.HardwareStatusInformation.RamFree;
                        cmd.Parameters["@DiskTotal"].Value = hardwarecomponent.HardwareStatusInformation.DiskTotal;
                        cmd.Parameters["@DiskFree"].Value = hardwarecomponent.HardwareStatusInformation.DiskFree;
                        cmd.Parameters["@LastUpdate"].Value = hardwarecomponent.HardwareStatusInformation.LastUpdate;
                        cmd.Parameters["@RamUnit"].Value = hardwarecomponent.HardwareStatusInformation.RamUnit;
                        cmd.Parameters["@GroupId"].Value = hardwarecomponent.GroupId;
                        cmd.Parameters["@Name"].Value = hardwarecomponent.DeviceId;
                        hardwareComponentId = (int)await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync();
                    }
                    importSoftwareComponentStatusesTasks.Add(ImportSoftwareComponentStatuses(hardwarecomponent.SoftwareComponents, monitoringInformationId, hardwareComponentId, trans));
                    importEodStatusesTasks.Add(ImportEodStatuses(eods, monitoringInformationId, hardwareComponentId, trans));
                }
                await Task.WhenAll(importSoftwareComponentStatusesTasks);
                await Task.WhenAll(importEodStatusesTasks);
            }
            catch
            {
                _logWrapper.Error($"Error in {nameof(ImportHardwareComponentStatuses)}");
                throw;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Import software component statuses
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="softwareComponents">Software components</param>
        /// <param name="monitoringInformationId">Monitoring information identifier</param>
        /// <param name="hardwareComponentId">Hardware component identifier</param>
        /// <param name="trans">Transaction</param>
        private async Task ImportSoftwareComponentStatuses(IEnumerable<SoftwareComponent> softwareComponents, int monitoringInformationId, int hardwareComponentId, SqlTransaction trans)
        {
            const string query = @" INSERT INTO  dbo.SoftwareComponentStatus(SoftwareComponentId,LastUpdate,Status,Version,MonitoringInformationId,HardwareComponentId)
                                    SELECT s.SoftwareComponentId,@LastUpdate,@Status,@Version,@MonitoringInformationId,@HardwareComponentId
                                    FROM dbo.SoftwareComponent s
                                    WHERE s.Name = @Name; ";

            try
            {
                var importTasks = new List<Task<int>>();
                foreach (var softwarecomponent in softwareComponents)
                {
                    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, trans.Connection, trans))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastUpdate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Version", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@MonitoringInformationId", SqlDbType.Int);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@HardwareComponentId", SqlDbType.Int);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@SoftwareComponentId", SqlDbType.Int);

                        cmd.Parameters["@LastUpdate"].Value = softwarecomponent.SoftwareComponentStatus.LastUpdate;
                        cmd.Parameters["@Status"].Value = softwarecomponent.SoftwareComponentStatus.Status;
                        cmd.Parameters["@Version"].Value = softwarecomponent.SoftwareComponentStatus.Version;
                        cmd.Parameters["@Name"].Value = softwarecomponent.Name;
                        cmd.Parameters["@MonitoringInformationId"].Value = monitoringInformationId;
                        cmd.Parameters["@HardwareComponentId"].Value = hardwareComponentId;
                        cmd.Parameters["@SoftwareComponentId"].Value = softwarecomponent.SoftwareComponentId;
                        importTasks.Add(cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync());
                    }
                }
                await Task.WhenAll(importTasks);
            }
            catch
            {
                _logWrapper.Error($"Error in {nameof(ImportSoftwareComponentStatuses)}");
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _using (trans = connection.BeginTransaction())_ -> does the Dispose need to run on the same thread as the initializer?

Answer (score 1):

New command in the loop is wasteful.  Create it once and loop on the values.

```
foreach (var softwarecomponent in softwareComponents)
{
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, trans.Connection, trans))
```

SQL has async methods [SqlCommand.BeginExecuteNonQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b6f9k7k.aspx);

It is one set of write heads on the other end. My experience is a single insert command will perform best.  For sure it has less impact on resources.

I am not even sure this will work. You don't mention enabling MARS.

> MARS operations are not thread-safe.

Comment: Are you sure? I am running insert in parallel with WhenAll

Comment: I can see what you are doing and in my opinion it is wasteful.

Comment: MARS is true. I don't see why would be important in my case that MARS is not thread safe. I am doing just inserts.

Comment: Uh, what if you catch an exception from another thread?

Comment: What then? In this case everything is in same transaction and it will rollback. Another thread from some another repository is another connection.If i get exception there than I will handle error there. Please give me more details what you think that is problem.

Comment: A little problematic if you don't know where the error came from.  I can't help you.  I think the design in general is flawed.